appengine-maven-plugin:2.8.1:deploy failing because it (incorrectly) believes the Java App Engine Components are not installed
Error is
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:2.8.1:deploy (default-cli) @ licence-server ---
[INFO] Staging the application to: c:\Source\wylas\wylas-licence-server\server\licence-server\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] Detected App Engine appengine-web.xml based application.
[INFO] Deleting the staging directory: c:\Source\wylas\wylas-licence-server\server\licence-server\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.081 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-05T11:06:44+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.8.1:deploy (default-cli) on project licence-server: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.8.1:deploy failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.AppEngineJavaComponentsNotInstalledException: Validation Error: Java App Engine components not installed. Fix by running 'gcloud components install app-engine-java' on command-line. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

GCloud component versions:
c:\Source\wylas\wylas-licence-server\server\licence-server>gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 502.0.0
app-engine-java 2.0.31
app-engine-python 1.9.114
beta 2024.11.15
bq 2.1.9
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.3.1
core 2024.11.15
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.31

Java Version
c:\Source\wylas\wylas-licence-server\server\licence-server>java --version
openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 17.0.5+8-adhoc..jdk17u)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 17.0.5+8-adhoc..jdk17u, mixed mode)

Maven Version
c:\Source\wylas\wylas-licence-server\server\licence-server>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: C:\Dev\apache-maven-3.9.9
Java version: 17.0.8, vendor: OpenLogic, runtime: C:\Dev\jdk-17.0.8.7
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

NB attempting to update the GCloud Java Components gives:
c:\Source\wylas\wylas-licence-server\server\licence-server>gcloud components install app-engine-java
All components are up to date.

Is there a work around?

Can you make sure to implicitly set the maven version in the .yaml configuration file? As per the Link even if you have a plugin for managing the Maven architecture, it is still needed to declare the plugin in your pom's build->plugins section for the configuration to take effect. Also make sure the file structure should look as per the Documentation.

Thanks @SandeepVokkareni. All plugins are declared in the plugins section, not the pluginManagement section. When did index.yaml and cron.yaml move to the root of the project? We have always deployed them out of the webapp/WEB-INF folder. And we have never used a src\main\appengine\app.yaml file

Can you make sure that the Maven tool targets the Java 17 runtime. You'll also need to verify that all of your dependencies are compatible with Java 17. Also edit the question by sharing the file structure.

@SandeepVokkareni it appears that it was being caused by a corrupted GCloud SDK installation folder. Setting the 'cloudSdkHome' param of the appengine-maven-plugin to a fresh installation GClouod SDK installation folder allowed appengine:deploy to succeed.

The issue in this case was that the GCloud SDK installation folder had become corrupted.
The solution was to install GCloud SDK into a new folder and change the 'cloudSdkHome' param of the appengine-maven-plugin to the new location.
